# Thread safety of a class variable in Rails - will this work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thread-safety, currency

I'm using the [Ruby Money gem](http://money.rubyforge.org/) in a multi-tenant (SaaS) Rails app, and am looking for a good way to make the `Money.default_currency` be set to an Account's preference for each request. I have several currency-related models in the app that use the Money class.

I have everything working properly in development, but I'm just looking for some feedback on whether or not the solution with have repercussions in production.

Here's what I did in my ApplicationController (irrelevant code removed for brevity):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_currency

  private

  def set_currency
    Money.default_currency = Money::Currency.new(current_account.present? && current_account.currency.present? ?
                                                 current_account.currency : 'USD')
  end
end
```

So the code above will set the `default_currency` class variable to the current account's preference, or default back to 'USD' if there isn't one.

By the way, here's the relevant `default_currency` code in the Money class:

```
class Money

  # Class Methods
  class << self

    # The default currency, which is used when +Money.new+ is called without an
    # explicit currency argument. The default value is Currency.new("USD"). The
    # value must be a valid +Money::Currency+ instance.
    #
    # @return [Money::Currency]
    attr_accessor :default_currency

  end
end
```

**So, will this work as expected in a multi-user setting? Anything else I need to do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most rails apps don't run in multithreaded mode - a given instance is only ever handling one request at a time (this is the default).

If your app was in multithreaded mode this would be dangerous - `Money.default_currency` could get changed halfway through a request by the new request that has just come in. If you did want to make this thread safe, you could use the `Thread.current` hash to have per thread values of `default_currency`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not running Rails in multi-threaded mode so that's what I figured. Just wanted to get another opinion, so thank you!

Comment: @summerville It has been a while since this question, but wanted to point out that as things move forward, there are increasingly cases where servers (e.g. unicorn, and even passenger) can be configured in a way that would allow certain multi-threaded operations to occur.  So you're probably safe ... for now, but I would suggest you either avoid cases like yours, and follow Frederick's advice to use Thread.current.    You're dealing with money here, so ... it matters if you get it wrong :-)